# lxml xpath() function does not work with correct XPath query

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am trying to evaluate some XPath queries using lxml library, however, it seems like it does not work, for some reason. Here's the code

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    xml = r'''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<unit xmlns="http://www.srcML.org/srcML/src" revision="0.9.5" language="Java" filename="File.java"><package>package <name><name>com</name><operator>.</operator><name>samples</name><operator>.</operator><name>e978092668</name></name>;</package>
<class><annotation>@<name>Path</name></annotation>
<specifier>public</specifier> class <name>Correct</name> <block>{
    <decl_stmt><decl><annotation>@<name>Inject</name></annotation>
    <specifier>private</specifier> <type><name>JsonWebToken</name></type> <name>field</name></decl>;</decl_stmt>
}</block></class>
</unit>'''.encode("UTF-8")

    xpath = '''unit/class[((descendant-or-self::decl_stmt/decl[(type[name[text()='JsonWebToken']] and annotation[name[text()='Inject']])]) and (annotation[name[text()='Path']]))]'''
    tree = etree.fromstring(xml)
    a = tree.xpath(xpath)
    print(len(a)) # returns 0 (matches)
```

I tried the exact same xpath query with the exact same XML string on [freeformatter.com](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) and it works and shows the match. I don't know what's wrong with my own code, because, for the most part, I followed the official tutorial on the website.

Edit 1:

Trying with namespaces.

```py
    xpath = '''src:unit/src:class[((descendant-or-self::src:decl_stmt/src:decl[(src:type[src:name[text()='JsonWebToken']] and src:annotation[src:name[text()='Inject']])]) and (src:annotation[src:name[text()='Path']]))]'''
    tree = etree.fromstring(xml)
    a = tree.xpath(xpath, namespaces={
        "src": "http://www.srcML.org/srcML/src"
    })
    print(len(a)) # returns 0 (matches)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I tested your xpath. It misses the namespace to use. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32127488/3710053

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed added the namespace, still does not work.

Comment: @JackFleeting if `print len(a)` returns 0, it means there is no match. The expected output is a positive value.

Comment: Update your code, where you show how you are using the namespace, so we can help you.

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed I have already updated the question description. Is there anything missing?

Comment: @mzjn basically it's like writing PMD style rules, if there's not a match then probably it means XML violates the rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you do:

```py
tree = etree.fromstring(xml)
```

`tree` has the context `src:unit` so your xpath is looking for a child `src:unit` in `src:unit`. (If you `print(tree.tag)` you'll see `{http://www.srcML.org/srcML/src}unit`.)

Try starting the xpath at `src:class`...

```py
xpath = '''src:class[((descendant-or-self::src:decl_stmt/src:decl[(src:type[src:name[text()='JsonWebToken']] and src:annotation[src:name[text()='Inject']])]) and (src:annotation[src:name[text()='Path']]))]'''
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah it works with your suggestion. Now, I was wondering if there's a way to leave the xpath as is, but change the tree context to a level higher so that `src:unit` would also work. By looking at XML, I see that `unit` is the topmost node anyways. But I'm just curious if there is a possibility of creating a pseudo-root for that.  Not sure if that makes sense though.

Comment: @MansurGulami - That makes sense. You could try either `tree = etree.ElementTree(etree.fromstring(xml))` or `tree = etree.parse(io.BytesIO(xml))`, but in both cases I had to make the xpath absolute by adding `/` to the beginning (`/src:unit...`).