# Lxml xpath() Is Only Returning an Empty List

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, parsing, xpath

I'm trying to parse an Visual Studio project file with lxml and Python 2.7. However, no matter what I do, I cannot get the xpath() function to return anything besides an empty list. I even pretty printed my etree right before calling xpath() to make sure everything in the etree looked good.

Here is an example of one of the many xpath paths I've tried

```
v = self.tree.xpath('/Project/ItemDefinitionGroup[1]/Link/LinkerScript')
```

And here is a snippet of the Visual Studio project file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|VisualGDB">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>VisualGDB</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|VisualGDB">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>VisualGDB</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <VCProjectVersion>16.0</VCProjectVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{52B4E371-970C-43AA-AE3C-3D3C44EB7627}</ProjectGuid>
    <BSP_ID>com.sysprogs.arm.stm32</BSP_ID>
    <BSP_VERSION>2021.02</BSP_VERSION>
    <InPlaceBSPSubdir />
    <RelativeBSPPath />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="Configuration" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|VisualGDB'">
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Configuration" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|VisualGDB'">
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="Shared">
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|VisualGDB'">
    <GNUConfigurationType>Debug</GNUConfigurationType>
    <ToolchainID>e368e833-a86e-4937-91b5-de07ceafe604</ToolchainID>
    <ToolchainVersion>10.3.1/(GNU/r0</ToolchainVersion>
    <MCUPropertyListFile>$(ProjectDir)stm32.props</MCUPropertyListFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|VisualGDB'">
    <ToolchainID>e368e833-a86e-4937-91b5-de07ceafe604</ToolchainID>
    <ToolchainVersion>10.3.1/(GNU/r0</ToolchainVersion>
    <MCUPropertyListFile>$(ProjectDir)stm32.props</MCUPropertyListFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|VisualGDB'">
    <ClCompile>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories></AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions></PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <AdditionalOptions>-fms-extensions</AdditionalOptions>
      <CLanguageStandard>C11</CLanguageStandard>
      <CPPLanguageStandard />
      <ForcedIncludeFiles>..\Source\Assert\Assert.h;%(ForcedIncludeFiles)</ForcedIncludeFiles>
      <CharSign>Unsigned</CharSign>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <LibrarySearchDirectories>%(Link.LibrarySearchDirectories)</LibrarySearchDirectories>
      <AdditionalLibraryNames>%(Link.AdditionalLibraryNames)</AdditionalLibraryNames>
      <AdditionalLinkerInputs>%(Link.AdditionalLinkerInputs)</AdditionalLinkerInputs>
      <AdditionalOptions>-specs=nano.specs -specs=nosys.specs -lc -lm</AdditionalOptions>
      <GenerateMapFile>true</GenerateMapFile>
      <MapFileName>Project.map</MapFileName>
      <LinkerScript>STM32F437VI_flash.lds</LinkerScript>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
</Project>
```

There's more to the file, but the file name in the second to last line `<LinkerScript>STM32F437VI_flash.lds</LinkerScript>` is what I'm trying to get.

I've tried making my own paths as well as getting some generated ones from: [Online xpath Ganerator](https://xmltoolbox.appspot.com/xpath_generator.html)

I've tried the simplest xpaths I can think of, but xpath() still returns nothing but an empty list. Does anyone have any ideas what could be going on?

Comment: You need to take the XML namespace into account (defined by `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"`). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8056239/407651

Comment: start by uploading a **VALID** xml - the current one is not.

Comment: @balderman Sorry about that! I threw a `</ItemDefinitionGroup>` and a `</Project>` on the end that should make it valid.

Comment: Scott - I managed to fix it and extract the required info. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks! @mzjn I'll definitely look more into the namespace. I want to figure out how to do things with the xpath() for the future.

Answer (score 1):

The below seems to work (no external lib is used - just *ElementTree*).
The idea is use the namespace as part of the search string.
Read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces).

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|VisualGDB">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>VisualGDB</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|VisualGDB">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>VisualGDB</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <VCProjectVersion>16.0</VCProjectVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{52B4E371-970C-43AA-AE3C-3D3C44EB7627}</ProjectGuid>
    <BSP_ID>com.sysprogs.arm.stm32</BSP_ID>
    <BSP_VERSION>2021.02</BSP_VERSION>
    <InPlaceBSPSubdir />
    <RelativeBSPPath />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="Configuration" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|VisualGDB'">
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Configuration" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|VisualGDB'">
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="Shared">
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|VisualGDB'">
    <GNUConfigurationType>Debug</GNUConfigurationType>
    <ToolchainID>e368e833-a86e-4937-91b5-de07ceafe604</ToolchainID>
    <ToolchainVersion>10.3.1/(GNU/r0</ToolchainVersion>
    <MCUPropertyListFile>$(ProjectDir)stm32.props</MCUPropertyListFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|VisualGDB'">
    <ToolchainID>e368e833-a86e-4937-91b5-de07ceafe604</ToolchainID>
    <ToolchainVersion>10.3.1/(GNU/r0</ToolchainVersion>
    <MCUPropertyListFile>$(ProjectDir)stm32.props</MCUPropertyListFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|VisualGDB'">
    <ClCompile>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories></AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions></PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <AdditionalOptions>-fms-extensions</AdditionalOptions>
      <CLanguageStandard>C11</CLanguageStandard>
      <CPPLanguageStandard />
      <ForcedIncludeFiles>..\Source\Assert\Assert.h;%(ForcedIncludeFiles)</ForcedIncludeFiles>
      <CharSign>Unsigned</CharSign>
    </ClCompile></ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <Link>
      <LibrarySearchDirectories>%(Link.LibrarySearchDirectories)</LibrarySearchDirectories>
      <AdditionalLibraryNames>%(Link.AdditionalLibraryNames)</AdditionalLibraryNames>
      <AdditionalLinkerInputs>%(Link.AdditionalLinkerInputs)</AdditionalLinkerInputs>
      <AdditionalOptions>-specs=nano.specs -specs=nosys.specs -lc -lm</AdditionalOptions>
      <GenerateMapFile>true</GenerateMapFile>
      <MapFileName>Project.map</MapFileName>
      <LinkerScript>STM32F437VI_flash.lds</LinkerScript>
    </Link>
</Project>'''
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
print(root.find('.//{http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003}LinkerScript').text)
```

output

```
STM32F437VI_flash.lds
```

Comment: Oh sweet! That actually works! I was trying figure it out using the xpath() function, but this work for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Glad I managed to help. Please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

After going through some of the other queries that I needed to write for this parser, I figured out the solution I was looking for using xpath(). Thanks to the comment from @mzjn. There might be more eloquent ways to do this, but here it is:

**The namespace reference was the big thing I was missing.** This post is what I based my solution on: [how to query xml data with namespaces using xpath in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127247/how-to-query-xml-data-with-namespaces-using-xpath-in-python)

I defined my namespace and then added the namespace prefix on the front of each XML tag in my query.

```
ns = {'n': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'}
v = self.tree.xpath('/n:Project/n:ItemDefinitionGroup[1]/n:Link/n:LinkerScript', namespaces=ns)
```

Works like a charm, and it was easy to adapt for more complex queries!

Thanks also to @balderman whose answer helped me make some progress after being stuck for a while.